# Apollo Client: Can't put ReactHook after Conditional, but React Hook needs data available only after conditional?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

Order of Operations issues it seems.

1. Can't use a React Hook after a Conditional as I get this error:

   Error: Rendered more hooks than during previous render
2. This React Hook is 3rd party and can't change it. This React Hook needs data that is only available after the conditional...so I get another error of data not defined
3. Ok, how about declare a new variable (empty array) to put in 3rd party React hook before conditional? Then after conditional reassign with data that shows up. Doesn't work either... as I get error that it is using the same key...well because the 3rd party hook is getting an empty array variable first. What do I do?

````
   import { libraryHook } from '3rd party'
   import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
    
    const myComponent = () => {
      const {loading, error, data } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, { variables: {someVariable: fromDatabase}
      
      const { 3rdpartyVariable } = libraryHook(data);

      // Hook needs to be above conditional so I don't get error,
      //but data only available after conditional.

      if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
      if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
    
    console.log(data);
    
    return(
      <div>
        {data}
      </div>
    )
    
    }
    
    export default myComponent;```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is another hook called `useLazyQuery` that can be used in this case, it provides you a function that can be called to execute your query. This is how you can do it

```
import { gql, useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_GREETING = gql`
  query GetGreeting($language: String!) {
    greeting(language: $language) {
      message
    }
  }
`;

function Hello() {
  const [loadGreeting, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_GREETING,
    { variables: { language: "english" } }
  );
  if (called && loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>
  if (!called) {
    return <button onClick={() => loadGreeting()}>Load greeting</button>
  }
  return <h1>Hello {data.greeting.message}!</h1>;
}
```

[Refer Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery)

Comment: I don’t get how this would work. I would use the 3rd party hook that needs data and placed above all conditionals to avoid errors, but data isn’t available before conditional loading.  I want data to come automatically without a button.